# What was the very first Apple product?

Tags: history, apple-inc

I am wondering what was the very first apple product? I have heard that they have made PDA's and drawing tablet type products in the past (early days)?

Comment: Despite the popularity of this, I'm going to close it for now. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve and this seems more like something that we'd want to put in a wiki on apple as opposed to a Q&A site focused on solving problems faced by users of Apple products.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Their first product was the **[Apple I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I)** computer, hand-built by Steve Wozniak and first demonstrated in 1976.

[image]

You'll find plenty of details about Apple's early years in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.#1976.E2.80.931980:_The_early_years) of the Apple, Inc [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc).

Comment: Bah! 53 seconds too slow! :P

Comment: @Scottie: Heh :) The photo of Jobs & Wozniak that you came up with is pretty nice though – let's see if that earns you more votes ;)

Answer (score 13):

"The Apple I, Apple's first product. Sold as an assembled circuit board, it lacked basic features such as a keyboard, monitor, and case. The owner of this unit added a keyboard and a wooden case."

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I

[image: The Steves, Jobs & Woz]

The above picture is from April 24, 1984 at the flamboyant "Apple II Forever" introduction of the Apple IIc. This was shortly after the introduction of the Macintosh, so Apple wanted to assure dealers the Apple II would continue to be supported. The Apple II product line continued until the final Apple IIGS model was discontinued in December 1992. That's the Apple I at the bottom.